# Android custom library access internal class

Tags: android, android-library

I have a custom library module with some dependency and custom made class. From other app projects I can access this lib dependency using :

```
implementation('com.github.mylib.test:testlib:1.0.5') {
    transitive = true
 }
```

And from there I can make use of all dependency that are added to my lib.

But I can not access custom classes that I made inside my lib

```
open class Slave: AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

}

The above activity declared inside my lib ca not be accessed from other project. Same with custom helper classes;

How can I access custom classes that I declare inside my lib from other projects?
Thanks

Comment: i figured out how to make it working. The new problem : if a add a *.jar to my library module.... that jar is not visible in other projects where implement my libraray. How can i make it visible ; The error is : ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency

Comment: Sounds like you should post a new question for that.